# Which statement is better and more secure for SQL Injection?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-injection

Which statement is better and more secure to prevent any sql injection, or are they the same?

```
com.CommandText = "update tblTableName set Name=@name, Age=@age WHERE ID=1";
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name.ToString());
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age.ToString());
```

OR

```
com.CommandText = @"update tblTableName set Name=" + name.ToString() + ", Age=" + age.ToString() + " WHERE ID=1";
```

OR

```
com.CommandText = "update tblTableName set Name=" + HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(name.ToString()) + ", Age=" + age.ToString() + " WHERE ID=1";
```

OR is there a better way.?
appriciate your help and opinion.

Comment: of course first one. because HtmlEncode would never help us to prevent sql injection.

Comment: the first one... -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only first one prevents [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

You don't use any [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) and [parameterized sql](http://blog.codinghorror.com/give-me-parameterized-sql-or-give-me-death/) in your second or third example. I can send them `18; DROP TABLE tblTableName` in your `age` variable. Creating html-encoded string with `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` method doesn't help either.

Also don't use `AddWithValue` method. It *may* generate unexpected results sometimes. Use `.Add()` method overloads to specify your column type and size explicitly.

Read: [Can we stop using `AddWithValue()` already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Comment: how would you use paremeter in this example:    com.CommandText = "update tblTableName set Notes = convert(nvarchar(4000),Notes) + '. " + notes + "' WHERE ID=1";

Comment: @Kamiran You can parameterize your `Notes` as `com.CommandText = "update tblTableName set Notes = convert(nvarchar(4000), @Notes) WHERE ID=1";` then you can it's value with `com.Parameters.Add("@Notes", ...);` fro example.

Comment: did you notes that i am trying to append more text to Note ?

Comment: @Kamiran What do you mean by that? You can only add the size of `nvarchar(4000)` of it. Or do you mean multiple parameter value in the same parameter? You can't do that as far as I know.

Comment: dear, what i want is : I have a field called Notes. I want to add more text to existing text in that field, not replacing the existing text using parameters

Comment: @Kamiran Then you can do it like; `update tblTableName set Notes = Notes + convert(nvarchar(4000) ...` for example.

Answer (score 0):

Only first, its prevent to sql injection.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/puranindia/parameterized-query-and-sql-injection-attacks/